# Advise to filter yearmonth

Tags: r, linear-regression, forecasting

I'm solving the exercises from book **Forecasting:Principles and Practice 3rd edition**

On chapter 7 ex 1 I want to filter Jan 2014 month from `tsibbledata:vic_elec` and summarise data by day, here's the code :

```
jan14_vic_elec <- vic_elec %>%
  filter(yearmonth(Time) == yearmonth("2014 Jan")) %>%
  index_by(Date = as_date(Time)) %>%
  summarise(
    Demand = sum(Demand),
    Temperature = max(Temperature)
  )
```

This chunk on the `filter()` functions gives an error :

1. Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. i Input `..1` is
2. `yearmonth(Time) == yearmonth("2014 Jan")`. x function
3. 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package '`Rcpp`'

Can somebody help ?

Comment: I am unable to re create this error, that code chunk works for me did you install and load the package fpp3?

Comment: Most likely you haven't loaded `dplyr` so you are using `stats::filter()`.

Comment: it keeps giving error, already tried to update packages and select filter by dplyr:: , but it keeps going.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new r window, and do this.
It should work!

Main issue is you have some package clashes. Hence start in a new window

```
library(fpp3)

jan14_vic_elec <- vic_elec %>%
  filter(yearmonth(Time) == yearmonth("2014 Jan")) %>%
  index_by(Date = as_date(Time)) %>%
  summarise(
    Demand = sum(Demand),
    Temperature = max(Temperature)
  )
```

Comment: already had loaded the package, same problem. Thanks for you trying to help

Comment: problem is in yearmonth

Comment: solved with as.yearmon from zoo package